# How to read lines from txt file after button press in Java

Tags: java, file, jbutton, bufferedreader

I want to be able to read four lines from a txt file each time a button is pressed until there are no more lines to be read. When I press the button the first time, the first four lines are read. The problem is that when I press the button the second time it won't read the next four lines.
The txt file looks like this

```
one
two
three
four

five
six
seven
eight
```

should I not be creating a BufferedReader every time I press the button?

```
public void fnext() {  
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fr));

        if(!br.ready()) {
            br.close();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No more data");
        }

        text = br.readLine() + " ";
        text += br.readLine() + " ";
        text += br.readLine() + " ";
        text += br.readLine() + " ";
        br.readLine();

        p.setText(text);

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(FileHandler.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
```

Comment: What happens at the second click? Your "No more data" message? And more to the point - check if closing the reader after usage helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare BufferedReader outside this function.

should I not be creating a BufferedReader every time I press the button?
Yes, if you create the object every time you click a button, it will read top 4 lines every time.